# Loading local data into a WebView with "loadHtmlString" or "loadRequest"?

Tags: uiwebview, xamarin.ios

I'm testing the WebView as a RichTextEditor.
I've noticed there are 3 methods to load data into it, so I googled to find out which are the differences between them, but find no clear answer.
Could someone please give me some insight about that?

Am I right supposing it's best to use `loadHtmlString` for local content and `loadRequest` for web content?

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three [recipes](http://api.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIWebView) in the MonoTouch docs (see bottom of page) that pretty clearly illustrate the three methods.

- LoadData() - load non-HTML data, can specify MIME type
- LoadRequest() - load content using async HTTP request
- LoadHTMLData() - load an HTML string

Comment: Thanks! that was the link I was searching for!